# Strange behavior with c++ io

Tags: c++, io, zlib

I am using zlib to compress data for a game I am making.  Here is the code I have been using

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "zlib.h"
#include "zconf.h"

using namespace std;

void compress(Bytef* toWrite, int bufferSize, char* filename)
{
    uLongf comprLen = compressBound(bufferSize);
    Bytef* data = new Bytef[comprLen];
    compress(data, &comprLen, &toWrite[0], bufferSize);
    ofstream file(filename);
    file.write((char*) data, comprLen);
    file.close();
    cout<<comprLen;
}

int main()
{
    const int X_BLOCKS = 1700;
    const int Y_BLOCKS = 19;
    int bufferSize = X_BLOCKS * Y_BLOCKS;
    Bytef world[X_BLOCKS][Y_BLOCKS];
    //fill world with integer values
    compress(&world[0][0], bufferSize, "Level.lvl");
    while(2);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now I would have expected the program to simply compress the array world and save it to a file.  However I noticed a weird behavior.  When I prited the value for 'comprLen' it was a different length then the created file.  I couldn't understand where the extra bytes in the file were coming from.

Comment: Internal housekeeping data of the file compression method itsel I would guess.

Comment: are you working on windows? 
try std::ofstream file(filename, std::ios::out | **std::ios::binary**);

Comment: but I only write comprLen bytes to the file in the first place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary mode:

```
std::ofstream file(filename, std::ios_base::binary);
```

without the `std::ios_base::binary` flag the system will replace end of line characters (`\n`) by end of line sequences (`\n\r`). Suppressing this conversion is the only purpose of the `std::ios_base::binary` flag.

Note that the conversion is made on the bytes written to the stream. That is, the number of actually written bytes will increase compared to the second argument to `write()`. Also note, that you need to make sure that you are using the `"C"` locale rather than some locale with a non-trivial code conversion facet (since you don't explicitly set the global `std::locale` in your code you should get the default which is the `"C"` locale).

Comment: are conversion facets applied to data written by `ostream::write()` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: `std::filebuf` (well, actually, `std::basic_filebuf<...>`) uses `std::codecvt<...>` to convert between the internal and the external encoding. `std::ostream` in general doesn't apply the code conversion facets: in the standard C++ library only the file stream use this facet.